# Why aren't options saving to database?

Tags: php

With this code, the selected options are saved to the database:

```
<select name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="chzn-select" multiple="true"
    <option value="US" <?php $val = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true ); if ( is_array( $val ) ) { if ( in_array( "US", $val ) ) { echo "selected='selected'"; } else { echo ""; } } ?> >United States</option>
    <option value="TH" <?php $val = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true ); if ( is_array( $val ) ) { if ( in_array( "TH", $val ) ) { echo "selected='selected'"; } else { echo ""; } } ?> >Thailand</option>
    ...
</select>
```

With this code, they are not:

```
<select name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="chzn-select" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Select Countries">
<?php
$countries = array('US' => 'United States', "TH" => "Thailand");
$vals = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true );
foreach($countries as $key => $value) { 
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key;?>"
    <?php echo (is_array( $vals ) && in_array( $key, $vals ) ) ? "selected='selected'" : ''; ?> >
    <?php echo $value;?>
    </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Why not?

This is how options are sent to the database:

```
/* Put locations in the database. */
function csmi_update_locations( $menu_id, $menu_item_db_id, $args ) {
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', true );
    if ( isset( $_POST[ 'menu-item-visibility' ][ $menu_item_db_id ] ) ) { 
        $new_meta_value = $_POST[ 'menu-item-visibility' ][ $menu_item_db_id ]; 
        if ( !isset( $new_meta_value ) ) {
            delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', $meta_value );
        }
        elseif ( $meta_value !== $new_meta_value ) {
            update_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, 'locations', $new_meta_value );
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the HTML in view source as requested.

```
<p class="field-visibility description description-wide">
...
    <select name="menu-item-visibility[4][]" id="edit-menu-item-visibility-4" class="chzn-select" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Select Countries">
        <option value="US"  > United States </option>
        <option value="TH"  > Thailand </option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: can you share the part of your code, which saving data to a DB?

Comment: Sure, will add it.

Comment: Try this <option value="<?php echo $key;?>"
Add double quote for option value

Comment: Use it `<option value="<?php echo $key;?>"<?php echo (is_array( $vals ) && in_array( $key, $vals ) ) ? "selected='selected'" : ''; ?> >
    <?php echo $value;?>
    </option>` in your foreach it and check

Comment: you missed quotes around `value` inside `foreach`,check my comment

Comment: as @Amit Visodiya mentioned, you forgot to add `"`

Comment: I tried that. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like this:

```
<select name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="chzn-select" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Select Countries">
<?php
$countries = array('US' => 'United States', "TH" => "Thailand");
$vals = get_post_meta( $item_id, 'locations', true );
foreach($countries as $key => $value) { 
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key;?>"
    <?php echo (is_array( $vals ) && in_array( $key, $vals ) ) ? "selected='selected'" : ''; ?> >
    <?php echo $value;?>
    </option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: You were missing double-quotes around value value="<?php echo $key;?>"

Comment: Hi Atif, It's the same with or without the quotes. :/

Comment: Did you check HTML of your checkboxes?? what is HTML?

Comment: All the HTML is included. Again, the first select box code without the array and loop works fine.

Comment: I am talking about second code (PHP Code). Does it also generates same HTML. Please check in "View Page Source"

Comment: Ah, Ok. I will add the HTML output to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is embarrassing. The problem was with my version of WordPress. Please disregard.